# I'm calling the Google Analytics Realtime API and getting back a JSON object. I need a script to determine if a value has changed

Tags: bash, shell, json

I'm calling the Google Analytics API with an HTML page containing Javascript calls. It returns a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "rows": [
    [
      "Submit",
      "6"
    ]
  ]
}
```

I'm currently outputting the raw JSON on my page in a div `<div id="response"></div>` on `gaAnalytics.html` using jQuery after I get it back from the Google Analytics API:

```
var obj = JSON.stringify(resp.result);
data = JSON.stringify($.parseJSON(obj), null,2) 
$('#response').text(data);
```

Now, I have a bash script that calls a USB LED light that lights up when I call it. I have it in `blinkFunctions.sh`:

```
function lightRed () {
    echo "light red!";
    ./blink1-tool -m 1 --rgb 255,0,0
}
```

How can I call `lightRed` every time the value after Submit changes?

Comment: keep 2 files, prev.Json, curr.Json and use bash comparison like `if [[ $(< prev.Json) != $(<curr.Json) ]] ; then lightRed ; fi`. The exact syntax details for `if [[ $(< prevJson!=$(<curr.Json) ]]...` will depend on what is inside `*.Json`. Get some sort of attempt at this into a shell script and then post with samples of data, and exact error messages that you're getting. As it is, I'm surprized this has been voted closed as "too board", but it sounds interesting. Good luck.

Comment: hey shellter thanks for the response! yeah, it's going to be an interesting project if I figure out how to do it correctly. i'm unable to write files with javascript though. any other suggestions?